# How to effectively handle UTC DateTime to the user as Local time

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm saving all dates as Utc, but having trouble displaying local time to the user in an intelligent way. I might be overthinking this, but I wanted to apply the logic in mapping, at the member level, so that I could could be very specific at where a view is using a local time, and when a view is returning a local time that needs to be stored as Utc.

Most of the DateTime logic is handled during savechanges:

```
   foreach (var entry in entries)
   {
      switch (entry.State)
      {
         case EntityState.Added:
            ((IEntity)entry.Entity).CreatedBy = UserName;
            ((IEntity)entry.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ((IEntity)entry.Entity).IsDeleted = false;
            break;
```

These are elements that can't be changed directly by the end user, and only need to be presented correctly. DateTime coming from the user I'm converting to Utc, meaning search results are correct.

I'm using Automapper, and the following applies ToLocal but with every date:

```
ValueTransformers.Add<DateTime>(val => 
        DateTime.SpecifyKind(val, DateTimeKind.Local).ToLocalTime());
```

I couldn't get any value or type converter to work at a member level.

Comment: I expect that you also want to account for local date/time format? Eg US mm/dd/yy, UK dd/mm/yy?

Comment: You should use DateTimeOffset. And if you want full "knowledge" of local zone, store TimeZoneInfo.Id (string) coupled with the DateTimeOffset everywhere you want to use Local-Utc-Know zone conversions. It carries you to make a (small) migration on every table with a datetime. But it rewards you with full knowledge of the situation (to use it in current or future functions, and is more "complete")